# Wifi Scan Results giving me odd results

Tags: java, android, timer

I am trying to hold the BSSID and signal strength of various wifi scans. However, I only care about the four most recent scans. It works fine when it scans four times but then strange things start happening, and it's like the size of each scan (the number of results) are the same after about the 6th scan. Is there something wrong with this code? I store the results in a list of sets ( I keep only the four most recent sets though when I process the data)

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<HashSet<Pair>> addresses = new ArrayList<HashSet<Pair>>();
    List <ScanResults> results;


    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //This whole part of the code is run once every ten seconds through use of a timer
    mainWifi.startScan();
    results = mainWifi.getScanResults();


    int entry = addresses.size();

        if (entry == 4) { // already has 4 addresses
        addresses.remove(0); // remove the
                                                    // oldest
                                                    // set
                            entry = 3;
                        }
    addresses.add(entry, new HashSet<Pair>());

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

        addresses.get(entry).add(new Pair(results.get(i).BSSID,results.get(i).level));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

I recommend waiting for the [SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) Intent that is broadcast when [WifiManager.startScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan%28%29) finishes to store your newest Wifi list.

I also suggest using a for-each loop and creating a reference to your latest List rather then using get(). In your Activity:

```
List<List<Pair<String, Integer>>> addresses = new ArrayList<List<Pair<String, Integer>>>();
List<Pair<String, Integer>> list;
...

public void newWifiResults() {
    list = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
    if(addresses.size() > 3) {
        addresses.remove(0);

    results = mainWifi.getScanResults();
    for(ScanResult result : results) 
        list.add(new Pair<String, Integer>(result.BSSID, result.level));

    addresses.add(list);
    // call mainWifi.startScan() again after a delay
}
```

You catch `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` in a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // We are only listening for one type of intent, no verifying necessary 
        newWifiResults();
    }
}
```

If you put this in you Activity too as a nested / sub class, the onReceive() will easily be able to call newWifiActivity().

Lastly you need to create a reference to your receiver, in your Activity:

```
private WifiReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
```

In onCreate() or onResume(), register the receiver:

```
registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

And in the matching method (onDestroy() or onPause()) unregister your receiver:

```
unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
```

This is more involved, but your code will only run when a new result set has been returned from startScan().

Comment: When I process some of these scan results, I would like for it to no longer catch the  later scan results since I don't want it to affect my data. If that's the case, do I still use onCreate () or onResume() or can I use my own methods. For example, when I"m proccesing I can unregister, and reregister when I'm done processing

Comment: Additionally, if I scan every 10 seconds by using a timer, will I ever get results that come from before? For example I"m scanning now, but a result from a minute ago just finished, would it catch those or only catch those that come after my latest scan (ignoring results that come in from a previously scheduled scan)

Comment: "will I ever get results that come from before?" A quick test showed me that until a startScan() finishes all successive calls are ignored. "I would like for it to no longer catch the later scan results" If I understand your question: you don't want the new results changing the results that you are currently processing. This shouldn't be a concern, since you are scanning every ten seconds and (on my devices) a scan returns results in under a second. But you can ensure this won't happen by only calling for a new scan after the previous one has return and been processed.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around. IF it's taking more than, say 5 seconds to get results, I want to ignore those results altogther. Basically if I miss some results that is okay, but if I start a scan, I wish to get the results from the latest scan. If old results finished too late, just ignore those scans.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything to worry about... I don't believe there is a way to cancel a slow scan, but when the scan does finish you'll have the latest results possible. And if it takes over 10 seconds to process the results you have a have bigger problem one your hands... A frozen app and disgruntled user.